# Puzzling comes from within

Tags: logic-grid

People often say that the power to do things comes from within.
In this puzzle, maybe I have taken that a bit too literally...

[image: Grams of nono]

***I'm sure you will be able to find the sentence hidden inside this image.***
After all, the solution is within all of us ;)

Comment: I'm assuming the first thing everyone else is going to do is look here and say, "Hey, my name's in a puzzle!" (or maybe be disappointed that it's not?).

Comment: Nice quick one, but I enjoyed it :)

Comment: I'm flattered to be on this list.

Comment: @JoeZ. I'm flattered to be on the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Message:

> Caesar once said, "I came, I saw, I conquered." (punctuation added)

Solution:

> Treat it like a pic-cross puzzle. The numbers for each column/row indicate which squares should be blanked out, with spaces in between. The spaces are the letters in the quote.

Image:

> [image: Solved image]

Comment: So fast it won't even let me accept the answer yet. Wow. :)

Comment: I've been doing those types of puzzles for years :) Also, it's 2:30 in the morning and I can't sleep because I took a two hour nap this afternoon.